# jQuery: how do I append variables onto a form path?

Tags: jquery

Lets say the URL in my form is

```
action="/medias/new_from_disk?CKEditor=content_body&CKEditorFuncNum=1&langCode=en"
```

and the form has ID `myform`
how would I conjure a jQuery command to add to the action

```
&var=value
```

?

complete form:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data"
       id="myform"
       method="POST" 
       action="/medias/new_from_disk?CKEditor=content_body&amp;CKEditorFuncNum=1&amp;langCode=en">
 </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
$('#myform').attr('action', $('#myform').attr('action') + '&var=value');
```

More Info:

- http://api.jquery.com/attr/